# Does electric current through gases emit light?

Tags: energy, visible-light, electricity, electric-current, gas

Not electric spark or electric arc, just normal current through gases created by heating the air between cathode and anode as shown in the following video at 1:25.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg0-sLkAssg&t=9s

Is it true that when ions in the air combine to form neutral particles, they emit low-energy light that human eyes cannot detect?

Answer (score 1):

Neon tubes, as well as more advanced systems, such as [Helium-Neon laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium%E2%80%93neon_laser) are expressly built in order to produce light in gas filled tubes, as a result of kinetic energy of accelarated ions being transferred into electronic exitations of these or other ions, and then re-emitted as light. The classical experiment in thsi respect (although not necessarily with emission of light) is that of [Frank-Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment).